vscode not highlightig eslint errors
I am trying to set up a react project on vscode with eslint.
I want VsCode to highlight Eslint errors.
What I want for instance is (I don't succeed to have it, I have eslint highlights but they are not related to my rules):

what I did

On VsCode I have installed EsLint extension

check versions:


VsCode version: 1.88.1

>> npx --version
10.5.0

>> eslint --version
v9.1.1


create react app:

>> npx create-react-app -template=typescript my-app

>> cd ./my-app


init Eslint

>> npx eslint --init
✔ How would you like to use ESLint? · problems
✔ What type of modules does your project use? · esm
✔ Which framework does your project use? · react
✔ Does your project use TypeScript? · typescript
✔ Where does your code run? · browser
The config that you've selected requires the following dependencies:
globals, @eslint/js, typescript-eslint, eslint-plugin-react, eslint
✔ Would you like to install them now? · No / Yes
✔ Which package manager do you want to use? · npm

It creates a eslint.config.mjs file with:
import globals from "globals";
import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";
import tseslint from "typescript-eslint";
import pluginReactConfig from "eslint-plugin-react/configs/recommended.js";


export default [
  {languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser }},
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
  pluginReactConfig,
];


Add a rule on eslint.config.mjs

export default [
  {languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser }},
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
  pluginReactConfig,
  { rules: { "no-constant-condition": "error" } }
];


close and reopen VsCode, no error highlighted (I added constant condition in App.tsx)

In App.tsx:
const res = true ? 'A' : 'B';
console.log(res);


Notes
I do have EsLint highlights but they are not related to my rules:

I also tried adding the rule on first object in eslint.config.mjs.
export default [
  {languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser }, rules: { "no-constant-condition": "error" }},
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
  pluginReactConfig,
];

My package.json:
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.96",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "globals": "^15.1.0",
    "typescript-eslint": "^7.8.0"
  }
}

